# How does naming an anonymous function in JavaScript make a difference?

Tags: javascript

I am analyzing the following two urls from John Resig's site, but I am not understanding how giving a name to the anonymous function has made a difference.

My understanding is that the name given to an anonymous function can only be used inside the function definition, and nowhere outside of it, but in the following links it is making a huge difference

- http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#13
- http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#14

Any explanation or reference will be a great help.

I am still confused with the following lines in #14

```
var samurai = { yell: ninja.yell }; 
var ninja = {};
assert( samurai.yell(4) == "hiyaaaa", "The method correctly calls itself." );
```

How is Samurai.yell method still able to point ninja.yell when ninja is now pointing to a blank object.

Only difference between #13 and #14 is providing a name to the function expression in #14.

Is ninja.yell COPIED to yell and NOT referenced or these kind of NAMED function expression have global scope in some scenario's like this ?

> 

Same thing happens in #13 and #14, only difference is that function is named in #14 and unnamed in #13 plus ninja = {} in #14 and ninja = null in #13. Is there any hidden concept about NAMED FUNCTION EXPRESSIONS that I am missing which makes #14 workable and #13 not workable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not trying to be combative with Kolink, but he goes a bit too far in saying it is NOT a good example. What #14 has to do with (in the links you shared) are named function expressions (a different animal from function declarations). Regardlesss of where the function reference is passed, if you name your function expression, it will always have a way to call itself, from within itself. This name, that you give your function expression, is a name that only it knows; it does not exist in any external scope.

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope#Function_constructor_vs._function_declaration_vs._function_expression) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) on MDN, for a further discussion about function expressions vs. function declarations. The second link, at the bottom, has a heading about named function expressions. It **does** have a use; see [my Gist](https://gist.github.com/2141298) for an example of one-off recursive function, that adds nothing to the local or global variable scope (useful for one-off DOM traversal, for instance).

Also, Tobias (in his answer here) points out other good uses of named function expressions, namely, in debugging.

Comment: Thanks for making the answers more precise but I am still confused about #14 - How is Samurai.yell method still able to point ninja.yell when ninja is now pointing to a blank object.

Comment: Okay, here's how it works: anonymous function is assigned to `ninja.yell` when the object is composed via the object literal. The function object (because all JS functions are first-class objects) in `ninja.yell` is then assigned to `samurai.yell`. `ninja` is then wiped clean: it's assigned a blank new object. But `samurai.yell` still holds a reference to the original function object, so it isn't garbage collected; it lives on. As long as one reference to any object remains, no garbage collection happens and the object lives on. Make sense?

Comment: Thanks Paul for bringing the garbage collection point which I was missing to understand in #14 but still the same thing happens in #13 also but it doesn't work. Only difference is expression is named in #14 and unnamed in #13 plus ninja=null in #13 and ninja={} in #14. Is there still any hidden concept about named function expressions that I am missing and which makes #14 workable but not #13 ?

Comment: Ok I read your points more thoroughly and analyzed #13 and #14 once again. Got the point that there is one more difference between #13 and #14, #13 we call yell as ninja.yell and #14 it's just yell, exactly as you clarified in your point of garbage collection. It makes it clear now and I accept your answer as correct one. Thanks a lot Paul :)

Comment: Good answer Paul.  But it would appear that even without naming the function, it can still always call itself via `arguments.callee` as Resig's next example (#15) shows.  Even with `ninja` being set to null, the recursion through the anonymous function that `samurai` now references can work perfectly if the recursion happens via `arguments.callee`.  Are my observations and conclusions correct, or is there something I'm missing?  Thanks.

Comment: The111 - no, you're definitely correct. However, looking at the [MDN article on the subject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee) reveals that it doesn't work in ECMAScript 5's strict mode. That article also deals with other issues concerning it, and a bit of history. Finally, there are [performance considerations](https://github.com/BonsaiDen/JavaScript-Garden/issues/157), too, when using arguments.callee. But, you are definitely correct: you do NOT have to name your function expression to call it recursively.

Answer (score 7):

in the examples internally you can skip the additional access to the ninja object in #13

anonymous closure (accessing object `ninja` is needed although we are already in that context):

```
var ninja = { 
  yell: function(n){ 
    return n > 0 ? ninja.yell(n-1) + "a" : "hiy"; 
  } 
};
```

named closure can be called directly:

```
var ninja = { 
  yell: function yell(n){ 
    return n > 0 ? yell(n-1) + "a" : "hiy"; 
  } 
};
```

another advantage is that named closures enable stacktracing:

so assuming you do:

```
(function fooBar() { console.log(brazl); })();
// will create an error with "fooBar" in the stack trace instead of "anonymous function"
```

EDIT: although it might look like overhead sometimes it helps debugging during development and for example YUICompressor and Closure Compiler can strip these names if they are not essentially needed

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, the `yell` method is trying to access `ninja.yell`, regardless of which object calls it. Whereas in the second, it tries to call `yell` which exists because the function is named.

It is NOT a good example. A good example would use `this.yell` instead of `ninja.yell`, thus getting the `yell` method from the current object.

Comment: It's not simply that the function is named; it's a named function expression, not merely a function declaration (which must have a name). The difference is more than semantic. And a function having a way to always reference itself, given that scope can be injected via `call` or `apply`, and the original reference to the function deleted, makes named function expressions very useful, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

The site http://kangax.github.com/nfe/ is a great reference. Yes, as far as it is a function expression the name will only be available inside (e.g. for recursive calls, as in the demonstration) and also helps for debugging (e.g. in stack traces), because it sets the `name` property of the function.